# How to make a picture from the Internet appear when you click on the button? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

There is a button on layout. I need that when I click on the button, an image from the Internet appears below (that is, through a link).

I am a beginner kotlin developer in android studio and I don't understand how to link clicking on a button and the appearance of some element in a certain place

Answer (score 1):

Use GLide or Coil to load your image.
Both are open source and free and there is plenty of resources avaiable.

You just need to call the Glide/Coil to load the specific link which will result to showing the image in ImageView(in xml) or AsyncImage(in compose) when you click the button.